# Given a matrix A $\in$ $R^{3 \times 4}$ and a vector b $\in$ $R³$, let Sol(A,b)={$x \in R^n:Ax=b$}.

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove or show that does not exist:
(i) There exist a echelon matrix U $\in R^{3 \times 4}$ and b $\in R³$ such that Sol(U,b) is empty.
(ii) There exist a echelon matrix U $\in R^{3 \times 4}$ and b $\in R³$ such that Sol(U,b) has exactly one element.
(ii) There exist a echelon matrix U $\in R^{3 \times 4}$ and b $\in R³$ such that Sol(U,b) has infinite elements.\

Hello,I need some help with those proofs. Here's what I have so far:

Let $Col(U)$ be the column space generated by the columns-vectors the matrix U.
If $b \notin Col(U)$ then the solution of $U*x=b$ is empty.
And if $b \in Col(U)$ then we either have one possible solution for the system or several possible solutions.\

I read in the book that for every matrix $dim \text{ } Col(U) = dim \text{ } Row(U)$. So, I conclude that the maximum value of $dim \text{ } Col(U)$ would be 3, since the matrix has only 3 rows. Is that correct?

First, if $dim \text{ } Col(U) = 3$ then the columns of U form a basis for $Col(U)$. And:
Ux=b

[$U_{*1},U_{*2},U_{*3},U_{*4}$]*($x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$)=($b_1,b_2,b_3)$

I have to be honest and say that I'm not sure if this is the appropriate approach to prove. I mean, since $dim \text{ } Col(U) = dim \text{ } Row(U)$, does it mean that $Col(U)=Row(U)$? I think this cannot be true, since the row vectors are 4-vector and the columns vectors are 3-vector, so the vector space is different. Right?

However, if $dim \text{ } Col(U) = 3$ since there are 4 columns, does it mean that one of the columns can always be generated by the other three?

And finally, how can I use those information to prove the statements are true or false?

Answer (score 1):

Your anticipation is correct but this kind of approach may not work well since your approach is abstract. To be effective in this approach, your background of linear algebra has to be strong.

Another simple way to approach your exercise is that you can write $Ax = B$ as a system of linear equations. E.g., the first item (i) says that: Find a system of three linear equations of four unknowns so that the system has no solution. It would be easier than your abstract approach.